# cannot find symbol: method ceiling(int)

Tags: java, treeset

I can't understand why I am getting this error despite `ceiling` and `floor` functions are present in the `TreeSet` class. I get following error:

```
cannot find symbol: method ceiling(int)
```

Here is my Java code:

```
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.TreeSet;

 public static boolean containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(int[] nums, int k, int t) {
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        Integer x = set.floor(nums[i]);
        if(x!= null && x<= nums[i]+t)
            return true;
        Integer y = set.ceiling(nums[i]);
        if(y!= null && nums[i]<= y+t)
            return true;
        set.add(nums[i]);
        if(set.size()>k)
            set.remove(nums[i-k]);


    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is `Integer x = set.(nums[i]);` supposed to be?

Comment: Oops.. was trying different things before I copy-pasted.. It was supposed to be set.floor(nums[i]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

To

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
```

and you will be able to call the methods.  The methods ceiling and floor do not exist for just Set.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can't believe i made such a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your `set` variable type is `Set<Integer>` and not `TreeSet<Integer>` or `NavigableSet<Integer>` (an interface that `TreeSet` implements). If you want to call a method that belongs to `NavigableSet` you have to change type of your local variable `set` to `NavigableSet<Integer>` or you can cast current one before calling a method, e.g.

```
((NavigableSet<Integer>) set).ceiling(nums[i]);
```

Changing local variable type would be better option though.

Comment: As an aside, `ceiling` does exist in the [`NavigableSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface